# What's the default logging driver for docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, centos7

The docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/) said:

> To configure the Docker daemon to default to a specific logging driver, set the value of log-driver to the name of the logging driver in the daemon.json file, which is located in /etc/docker/ on Linux hosts or C:\ProgramData\docker\config\ on Windows server hosts. Note that you should create daemon.json file, if the file does not exist. ***The default logging driver is json-file.*** ...

[image]

---

BUT, WHY? Why on CentOS 7, it default use `journald`? I never specify `log-driver` in my `docker-compose.yml`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look into `/etc/sysconfig/docker`.

You might find among the list of options, the `--log-driver` being set to `journald`:

```
OPTIONS='... --log-driver=journald ...'
```

Either delete the `--log-driver=journald` and it will default to `json-file`, or chose another logging driver that fits your needs.

Reload the daemon and check if the problem persists:

```
systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: So, who changed the default behavior?

Comment: I do not have a CentOS installed, neither I know how the docker was exactly installed in your context, to reproduce and trace that, but the idea is that your SystemD service unit is loading the config from that file, and that file is setting the `--log-driver=journald`

Comment: I install docker & docker-compose by `yum install docker docker-compose`. And I make it auto start at boot by `systemctl enable docker`.